# A 404 error occurs on the about page

Tags: bug, status-completed, scope, derivatives

In the second slide of [the about page](https://askubuntu.com/about), the link to the ["official Ubuntu derivatives"](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/derivatives) gives a 404.

Answer (score 7):

The correct link, that *should* be used, is:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

That working link is given [in the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), but this broken link is given in the about page / tour:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/project/derivatives

So to fix this, someone with the ability to edit the about page (moderators?) should change the link there [to this](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives).